# pip install django graphos successful but import error

Tags: python, django, pip

this must be a very simple question, seams Im missing something obvious...

I did:

```
sudo pip install django-graphos
```

and got:

```
Successfully installed django-graphos
```

all good up to this point, then I went to settings.py and added:

```
'graphos',
```

to installed apps
but Im getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named graphos
```

what Im missing?

This is my pip freeze:

```
Cheetah==2.4.4
Landscape-Client==14.12
PAM==0.4.2
Pillow==4.0.0
PyYAML==3.10
Twisted-Core==13.2.0
Twisted-Names==13.2.0
Twisted-Web==13.2.0
apt-xapian-index==0.45
argparse==1.2.1
chardet==2.0.1
cloud-init==0.7.5
colorama==0.2.5
configobj==4.7.2
distro-info==0.12
django-graphos==0.3.29
djangorestframework==3.5.3
euca2ools==3.0.1
html5lib==0.999
jsonpatch==1.3
jsonpointer==1.0
lxml==3.3.3
oauth==1.0.1
olefile==0.44
prettytable==0.7.2
pyOpenSSL==0.13
pycurl==7.19.3
pyserial==2.6
python-apt==0.9.3.5ubuntu2
python-debian==0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2
requestbuilder==0.1.0-beta1
requests==2.2.1
six==1.5.2
ssh-import-id==3.21
urllib3==1.7.1
virtualenv==15.1.0
wheel==0.24.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
zope.interface==4.0.5
```

Comment: Whats the output of your `pip list`?

Comment: Can you please show me `pip freeze` command's output??

Comment: done, please check edited question

Comment: I don't know if this could be related, but Im also having a similar problem with Pillow, as you can see it is installed, but but I can use it. This is running in an ubuntu web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using sudo to install packages on the global system-wide Python installation; but this is not where your application is configured to work.

Your application is using a different environment (perhaps a virtual environment); and in that virtual environment you don't have the package installed.

You should make sure you activate your virtual environment before installing any packages; and don't use `sudo`.